# Incorrect data received on serial communication

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, softwareserial

I have two **Arduino UNO** connected with two wires, and ground, that exchange informations through **serial data.**
The communication is working with INT, but I am having troubles to receive correct characters. Instead of characters I'm only receiving numbers.

I tried every possible combination of `Serial.write()` or `Serial.println()`, with HEX and ascii, but it wouldn't work.

I do not know what I am doing wrong, if anyone could help me, I will appreciate.

**Transmitter :**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define TX 2
#define RX 3
#define ask 3
#define ER_LED 12

String dataline = "605030";
const byte code = 60;

SoftwareSerial syserial(RX, TX); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  syserial.begin(57600);
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //syserial.println(dataline); //NO
  //syserial.println(28, DEC); //ok for numbers
  
  Serial.println(dataline.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < dataline.length(); i++)
  {
    syserial.print((char)dataline[i]);
  }
  syserial.println();
  //syserial.write(234);
  //syserial.print('<');
  delay(4000);
}
```

**Receiver :**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define TX 2
#define RX 3
const byte ask = 3;
bool com_end;
#define ER_LED 7
#define AC_LED 5


SoftwareSerial syserial(RX, TX); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  syserial.begin(57600);
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (syserial.available())
  {
    Serial.println(syserial.read());
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

**Serial monitor on whatev b/s:**

```
21:19:36.408 -> 253
21:19:36.408 -> 255
21:19:40.421 -> 253
21:19:40.421 -> 255
21:19:44.495 -> 253
21:19:44.495 -> 255
```

**Monitor with *SySerial* on 57600 b/s:**

```
21:23:29.317 -> 241
21:23:33.308 -> 241
21:23:37.338 -> 241
21:23:41.328 -> 241
```

**Monitor with *SySerial* on 300 b/s:**

```
21:27:03.444 -> 255
21:27:07.731 -> 255
21:27:12.095 -> 255
21:27:16.335 -> 255
21:27:20.635 -> 255
```

**Update :**

I changed the pins on the UNO (TX ->2)(RX -> 3), and now i'm getting different numbers again. I must be doing something bad, but I can't understand what.

Comment: I get different numbers, instead of characters

Comment: please  open the content of the serial monitor window and paste it into your post ... format as code ... please **no** pictures

Comment: Yes, but they do not appear as characters

Comment: What numbers do you get at 9600 b/s?

Comment: Updated code with monitor output

Comment: Pins 0 and 1 on the Uno are for the HW serial. Perhaps if you used pins 3 and 4 for the SW serial, it may work as intended.

Comment: Changed it, doesn't work. I used to have pins 2 and 3

Comment: Are you swapping the wires? ie. RX on one Uno to TX on the other. Try using a lower baud rate for the software serial, 57600 is probably pushing it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Swapping the wires gives nothing on the monitor, so I think that the wires are in the right positions. I tried using both `300 b/s`, and `9600 b/s` for `syserial`, but it only changes a few numbers (_52 on 300 b/s, gives 53 on 9600 b/s_). The numbers seems to change when I use different baud rates

Comment: Don't you have an oscilloscope or logic analyzer at hand to _measure_ instead of _guessing_?

Comment: @the busybee I do not have any oscilloscopes, or logic analyzers. I would have tried with those if I could.

Comment: Well, then, double-check each SW/HW component and do baby-steps: for example, check by local loop-back that you have the right pins and software, transmit single bytes of clear patterns (0x01 to 0x80) with enough interval, and so on. It is always quite hard to do development without appropriate tools.

Comment: What do you mean _`each ""SW/HW"" component`_ ? At the moment I checked pins correspondence, I tried using different pins, and tried standard codes I could find online, but no luck so far...

Comment: Correct, the pins you use, the functions you call, the parameters of these functions. Did you try the suggestions? Please add new information to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: I would try using the hardware serial ports instead. And yes: the receiver can use the hardware port both for receiving from the other Arduino and for sending to the serial monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The communication is working with INT, but I am having troubles to receive correct characters. Instead of characters I'm only receiving numbers.*

Suggest you take a step back because you have code that has not been updated with what you have stated in subsequent comments and it is quickly becoming less clear what is going on.

On each UNO Use pins 2,3 and GND. **Don't connect anything else to either UNO.**

UNO ONE pin **2** connects to UNO TWO pin **3**

UNO ONE pin **3** connects to UNO TWO pin **2**

UNO ONE GND to UNO TWO GND

on UNO ONE run this code:

```
// RECEIVER
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SSerial(2,3); // RX, TX
void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600); // Arduino monitor hardware Serial
  SSerial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() { 
  // display whatever comes in on the software serial to the Arduino monitor (the hardware serial)
  if (SSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(SSerial.read());
  }
}
```

on UNO TWO run this code

```
// SENDER
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial SSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX
    void setup() {
      SSerial.begin(9600);
    }
    void loop() {
      SSerial.println("Simple Arduino SoftwareSerial Test");
      delay(1000);
    }
```

Open the serial monitor on UNO ONE and you will see "Simple Arduino SoftwareSerial Test" printed every second.

If you can't get that far, you have some other problem.

Are you using two UNOs on two different computers?
Are you using two UNOs on one computer, that is; running two instances of the IDE (may depend on OS - I do that all the time on Win 7 but I don't know about other OSs)?

See if you can get this far first and I think it will be easier to get the rest fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the setup you gave seems to be working, I will try to understand what was wrong in my previous code...